# NODEJS / PHP WSDL SOAP: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, node.js, soap, wsdl, object-reference

Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in Line ...

Already got lots of question related to this, but I am unable to make it work out, so posting this possible duplicate again.

Im missing something here in the request, but couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

I tried this in both PHP & NodeJS, and same error occurred in both.

```
<?php     
$wsdl = 'http://test.eprabhu.com/Api/Utility.svc?wsdl';

$params = array(
"UserName" => "CLIENT",
"Password" => "CLIENT12",
"OperatorCode" => 2,
"MobileNumber" => "9803111111",
"Amount" => 100,
"PartnerTxnId" => "P2019042205330171261"
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => true]);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
// gives
// Array
// (
//     [0] => MobileTopupResponse MobileTopup(MobileTopup $parameters)
//     [1] => RechargePinsResponse RechargePins(RechargePins $parameters)
//     ...
// )
print_r($client->__getTypes());
// gives
// Array
// (
//    [0] => struct InputMobileTopup {
//              string UserName;
//              string Password;
//              int OperatorCode;
//              string MobileNumber;
//              float Amount;
//              string PartnerTxnId;
//    }
//    [1] => struct ReturnTransaction {
//              string Code;
//              string Message;
//              string TransactionId;
//              string Data;
//    }
//    ...
// )

// $r = $client->MobileTopup($params);
// or 
$response = $client->__soapCall("MobileTopup", [$params]);
// gives error Object reference not set to an instance of an object
var_dump($response);
$xml = $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
print_r($xml);

// Also I tried using the class after looking into __getTypes result
$wsdl = 'http://test.eprabhu.com/Api/Utility.svc?wsdl';
class InputMobileTopup {
    public function __construct($UserName, $Password, $OperatorCode, $MobileNumber, $Amount, $PartnerTxnId) {
        $this->UserName = $UserName;
        $this->Password = $Password;
        $this->OperatorCode = $OperatorCode;
        $this->MobileNumber = $MobileNumber;
        $this->Amount = $Amount;
        $this->PartnerTxnId = $PartnerTxnId;
    }  
}

$InputMobileTopup = new InputMobileTopup("CLIENT", "CLIENT12", 2, "9803111111", 1000, "P2019042205330171261");
print_r($InputMobileTopup);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => true]);

$response = $client->__soapCall("MobileTopup", [$InputMobileTopup]);
var_dump($response);
$xml = $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
print_r($xml);
// Still the same error.
```

In NodeJS too, the same error occurs
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;

var url = 'http://test.eprabhu.com/Api/Utility.svc?wsdl&UserName=CLIENT';
var requestArgs = {
    'UserName': 'CLIENT',
    'Password': 'CLIENT12',
    'OperatorCode': 2,
    'MobileNumber': '9803111111',
    'Amount': 100,
    'PartnerTxnId': 'P201904220218335187'
};

var options = {
  'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  // 'soapAction': 'http://test.eprabhu.com/Api/Utility.svc?wsdl#MobileTopup',
  'soapAction': 'http://tempuri.org/IUtility/MobileTopup'
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {

    var method = client['MobileTopup'];
    method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
        //response envelope
        console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
        //'result' is the response body
        console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));

        console.log('Soap Header: \n', soapHeader);
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanx.
Please prioritize the answer for NodeJS. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your WSDL the function `MobileTopup` takes as parameter message of type `MobileTopup`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MobileTopupResponse MobileTopup(MobileTopup $parameters)
    [1] => RechargePinsResponse RechargePins(RechargePins $parameters)
    ...
)
```

on the other hand the type `MobileTopup` is defined like:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [85] => struct MobileTopup {
              InputMobileTopup MobileTopupRequest;
            }
    ...
)
```

so you have to call the function like this:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall("MobileTopup", ['MobileTopup' => ['MobileTopupRequest' => $params]]);
```

this returns (according to the params you have set)

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["MobileTopupResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["Code"]=>
    string(3) "021"
    ["Message"]=>
    string(30) "Duplicate Partner Txn ID Found"
    ["TransactionId"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Data"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I guess the same is true for node.js

**UPDATE**

In node.js the problem comes from your `requestArgs` object. it should be like this:

```
var requestArgs = {
    MobileTopupRequest: {
        UserName: 'CLIENT',
        Password: 'CLIENT12',
        OperatorCode: 2,
        MobileNumber: '9803111111',
        Amount: 100,
        PartnerTxnId: 'P201904220218335187'
    }
};
```

Comment: Good for php,it worked. thx... but for node its not working. we need to generte envelop and send in headers, nut inable to do it..

Comment: @SanjayKhadka I have updated the answer for node.js, please have a look

Comment: ty it worked ... only problem I had is I re-tried with this format just like in php
`{MobileTopup: MobileTopupRequest: { Username: .... } };`
Also I added a bounty to your answer... :)

Comment: btw can you explain one thing. How do you, or how can we know about the MobileTopupRequest request parameter format looking at the xml wsdl.. Is there a way to understand this?

Comment: @SanjayKhadka actually it is not declared in WSDL, so I was basing on your structure